# macro excel find a cell value that doesn't contain value or blank

Tags: vba, excel

In order for me to copy across a sheet, I first need the macro to know which employee it belongs to (Each employee has their own sheet name). In this new group of sheets to add to them, their is the occasional name in Column D. However the first cell has the heading "Reference" Some have the employee name, some are blank. What i want to do it find a cell with a value in it (Not blank) and doesn't contain the word "reference" as this just leaves the employees name. I want to take this and copy it to L1, a blank cell outside of the table

From here i will be able to copy it to their sheets by calling on L1 as the sheet name reference.

The code that I have, will copy reference over to L1 but i dont know how to do employee name as discribed above:

```
`With Sheet2
    Set Foundcell = Selection.find(What:="Reference", LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False)
End With
If Not Foundcell Is Nothing Then
    Foundcell.Copy
    Range("L1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
Else
    MsgBox "There is no tech name in this purchases sheet"
End If
'
End Sub`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a find last cell I was able to find the last one with an emplyees name in it

```
Sub EmployeeName()

LR = Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
On Error GoTo NoTechName
Cells(LR - 1, 4).Copy
Range("L1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Exit Sub
NoTechName:
MsgBox "There is no tech name in this purchases sheet"
End Sub
```

Easy done! 
Thanks for all help you guys have given me

Answer (score 0):

If the name is always in the cell immediately below your "Foundcell" whose value is "Reference" then you would just need to do the following in your "If Not FoundCell Is Nothing Then" block.

```
'Offset the Foundcell by 1 row and check if a value exists
If Foundcell.Offset(1).Value = "" Then
     MsgBox "There is no tech name in this purchases sheet"
Else
'If you follow a .Copy with a space and then a range, 
'it will copy the value into that range without the extra steps.
     Foundcell.Offset(1).Copy ActiveSheet.Range("L1")
End If
```

If your name is not immediately underneath, but it is the only other value in the column except for "Reference", then the following is one way to find that value.

```
'Use SpecialCells to find all cells with a value in the column where you found Foundcell
Dim rangeWithVal as Range
Set rangeWithVal = Foundcell.EntireColumn.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
If rangeWithVal.Count = 1 Then
     'Only the cell with "Reference" was found in the column
     MsgBox "There is no tech name in this purchases sheet"
Else 
     If rangeWithVal.Count > 2 Then
          'More than 2 cells with a value were found.
          MsgBox "Column " + Split(FoundCell.Address(1, 0), "$")(0) + " in this purchases sheet has two or more names"
     Else
         Dim rng as Range
         For Each rng in rangeWithVal
             If rng.Value <> "Reference" Then
                 rng.Copy ActiveSheet.Range("L1")
             End If
         Next rng
     End If
End If
```

Comment: This looks very usable, however there are a few errors, is `If rng.Value <> "Reference"` meant to be `If rng.Value <> "Reference"
Then`? And `Set rangeWithVal = Foundcell.EntireColumn.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)` is telling me that an object is required. Any help would be a treat

Comment: I definitely missed the "Then" at the end of the `If rnpg.Value <> "Reference"`. Sorry about that. I was able to replicate your "object is required" error. If FoundCell is Nothing, then it will throw this error when you try the `Set rangeWithVal`... line. If would recommend setting the above code within your already existing `If Not Foundcell Is Nothing Then`... block in order to avoid this problem.